# Состояние видимости Metro UI окна

Tags: winapi, windows-10

Существует ли способ узнать, является ли видимым Metro UI окно в Windows 10?

Я заметил, что с приходом Windows 10 появилось много проблем в WinAPI, т.ч. `EnumWindows()` стала возвращать не все окна. Например "start menu" окно, "action center", "battery level" и прочие окна, которые открываются из task bar, не энумерейтятся через `EnumWindows()` никак. Я использовал workaround, чтобы получить эти окна через `FindWindowEx()`, не знаю насколько надёжно, но это сработало и мне удалось получить `HWND` каждого из этих окон, а потом запросить их геометрию (что тоже удалось сделать успешно). Однако проблема в том, что, хоть мне и удалось получить все эти окна, я не знаю являются ли они видимыми на экране. Если я на получившем дескрипторе Metro UI окна пытаюсь вызвать `IsWindowVisible()`, возвращаемое значение всегда `TRUE`, т.е. виндоус говорит, что эти окна всегда видимые и открытые, независимо от того, видны ли они по факту на мониторе или скрыты.

Есть ли способ узнать, является ли фактически видимым подобное окно? (action center panel, battery level panel, network status panel, language switch panel etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл один способ как это определить, протестировал, вроде бы работает хорошо. Вместо того, чтобы запрашивать видимость окна через `IsWindowVisible()`, я стал дополнительно запрашивать `DWMA_CLOAKED` атрибут окна через `DwmGetWindowAttribute()`. Этот атрибут равняется нулю, когда окно является видимым на экране.

```
bool is_window_visible(HWND handle) {
    int cloaked = 0;
    ::DwmGetWindowAttrribute(handle, DWMA_CLOAKED, static_cast<LPVOID>(&cloaked), sizeof(cloaked)));
    return ::IsWindowVisible(handle) && cloaked == 0;
}
```